# Why isn't bootstrap responsive on my phone?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I created a simple site using bootstrap. I'm finding that when I decrease the width of the browser on my computer, it seems responsive (the width of the text box decreases, for example).

However when I open this url on my phone, it is a zoomed out version of the page.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

http://warm-oasis-9302.herokuapp.com/decks/new

Answer (score 7):

As per [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template), your site is NOT responsive until it contains this in the `<head>` tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) within your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```